# Find free conscant of ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I fount generating function of recerrence as a solution of ODE which include parameter L:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}e^{-2 \left(-x^L \text{LerchPhi}[x,1,L]-\text{Log}[1-x]\right)} x^{-1+L} \left(C[1]+\int_1^x -\frac{e^{2 \left(-t^L \text{LerchPhi}[t,1,L]-\text{Log}[1-t]\right)} (1-t)^2 t^{-L} \left(2 t-L t+L t^2-L t^L-2 t^{1+L}+L t^{1+L}\right)}{(-1+t)^3} \, dt\right)$$

Now I need to find C[1] knowing that for n less then L the members of recerrence are equal to n. 
I did it for L=2 (C[1]=1) and solution is

$$\frac{e^{-2 x} x}{(1-x)^2}$$

and for L=3 $$C[1]=\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } \text{Erfi}[1]}{2 e}$$ and solution is $$\frac{3 e^{-1-2 x-x^2} \sqrt{\pi } x^2 \text{Erfi}[1]}{2 (1-x)^2}+\frac{e^{-2 x-x^2} x^2 \left(\frac{e^{2 x+x^2}}{x}-\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } \text{Erfi}[1+x]}{2 e}\right)}{(1-x)^2}$$

Could you help me to find C[1] for any L ?

Here is ODE I solved: $$\frac{2 x-L x+L x^2-L x^L-2 x^{1+L}+L x^{1+L}}{(-1+x)^3}+(1-L) A[x]-\frac{2 x^L A[x]}{1-x}+x A'[x]=0$$

Comment: Just by curiosity, where is this coming from ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is general case of this task http://mathblag.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/fatmen.pdf My final goal is to find the solution of the discret parking problem and detarmine parking constants for any L. For L=2 it is known to be equal to 1/e^2. I found it for L=3.